# Tracking other websites' users (Analytics)

Tags: http, analytics

I was wondering if there was any (legal) way to track websites analytics of any random site.

What I mean is simple, is there a way to actually know how many people enter Google a month?

I read around and found that Alexa extrapolates data from users with their toolbar and some cookies, im not interested in that, I mean a true measurement.

Where would you have to start if you wanted to write something like this?

I guess this is no possible but I can´t *really* understand why, are there any illegal ways of doing this?

Comment: and your programming question is......

Comment: @KevinDTimm there would be if this was actually was a way to track it. Sorry if the question was not relevant enough! Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I read around and found that Alexa extrapolates data from users with their toolbar and some cookies, im not interested in that, I mean a true measurement.

Nope, there is no way to do that. That's why Alexa needs to rely on extrapolation.

You'll have to rely on what the sites tell you.

Some commercial sites use services like Nielsen  that keep an  "official" visitor count on whose basis advertising prices are calculated, but this is not the rule.

Comment: Thanks! I guess its something basic about http protocols. Regards

Comment: @Trufa yup: What clients a server is connected to, simply isn't public information. And imagine the awful security implications if it were!